# MSI GF65 Thin, no scheduled boot options in BIOS?

Tags: bios, scheduled-tasks

I would like to schedule my laptop to boot automatically each day.  But the BIOS appears to not have such a feature.  How can I boot on a schedule, or can I enable this feature on this machine?

Comment: If there's no X feature you can't enable X feature.

Comment: I was asking if it has the feature or not or if there is some other way to accomplish the same result. There are often many features that are not obvious or not enabled by default.